# Perl Authen::OATH and Google Authenticator - incompatible?

Tags: perl, google-authenticator

My understanding (which may obviously be wrong) is that the [Authen::OATH](http://search.cpan.org/~sifukurt/Authen-OATH-v1.0.0/lib/Authen/OATH.pm) module is compatible with the totp codes generated by the Google Authenticator App.  But it doesn't work for me, whereas a similar bit of ruby code does.  We're a perl shop here and it would help if anyone could point me in the right direction to save me from digging through both libraries line by line.

This ruby works compatibly:

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'rotp'

secret = "bqagf6ohx4rp3a67"

puts ROTP::TOTP.new(secret).now.to_s
```

This perl does not:

```
use Authen::OATH;

my $oath = Authen::OATH->new();

my $totp = $oath->totp(" bqagf6ohx4rp3a67" );

print "$totp\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very clear from the documentation, but `Authen::OATH` expects the unencoded passwords to `totp` and `hotp`. If that's not an option, you could try `decode_base32` from [Convert::Base32](http://search.cpan.org/~ikegami/Convert-Base32-0.05/lib/Convert/Base32.pm)

```
use Convert::Base32;
use Authen::OATH;

my $oath = Authen::OATH->new();

my $totp = $oath->totp( decode_base32( "bqagf6ohx4rp3a67" ) );

print "$totp\n";
```